# Calling "oDataModel.read" before "Return"

Tags: javascript, promise, odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

While executing function `returns` statement gets called before my `oDataModel.read` statement, that causes empty parameter passing.

How do I call `oDataModel.read` first & then call `return` statement.

```
var sUrl = "/sap/opu/odata/sap/(some name)/";
        var oDataModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(sUrl, false);
        var oPlant = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Plant", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, oContext.getAllData().Plant);
        var oStatus = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Status", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, oContext.getAllData().Status);
        var oPriority = new sap.ui.model.Filter("priority", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, oContext.getAllData().priority);
        var oFilter = new Array(new sap.ui.model.Filter({
            filters: [oPlant, oStatus, oPriority],
            and: true
        }));

            oDataModel.read("(some name)", {
            filters: oFilter,
            success: function (results, error) {
                //sap.m.MesageToast.show(results);
                var data = results.results;

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    aCustomSelectionVariant07.push({
                        path: "InspectionLot",
                        value1: data[i].InspectionLot,
                        operator: "EQ",
                        value2: null,
                        sign: "I"
                    });
                }
                //      var aCustomSelectionVariant07 =[];
                var oCustomSelectionVariant07 = {
                    path: "InspLotRsltRecgStatus",
                    operator: "BT",
                    value1: "1",
                    value2: "2",
                    sign: "I"
                };
                aCustomSelectionVariant07.push(oCustomSelectionVariant07);

                oCustomSelectionVariant07 = {
                    path: "InspectionLotType",
                    operator: "BT",
                    value1: "10",
                    value2: "11",
                    sign: "I"
                };
                aCustomSelectionVariant07.push(oCustomSelectionVariant07);


            },
            error: function (error) {
                sap.m.MesageToast.show(error);

            }
            return {
                selectionVariant: aCustomSelectionVariant07,
                ignoreEmptyString: true
            };
},
```

in above code `return` gets called first then it is going for `DataModel.read`

I want `DataModel.read` first then call to return.

Comment: If `DataModel.read` is asynchronous, you'll have to return a `Promise` that resolves when the read is finished. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Hi, Tried using Promise but not working as expected.

Comment: Then what did you expect?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to asynchronous programming. You have two options:

- Passing a callback to your function which handles the returned value
  (uncool)
- Using promises (cool)

I will try to guide you through the second (cool) option.

Say you have a function which does stuff async

```
getSomeStuff: function() {
    // some code
    oModel.read(sPath, {
        success: function() {
            myStuff = [1,2,3,4];
        },
        error: function() {}
    });

    // when this line is reached, success has not been called and myObject is empty
    return myStuff;
}
```

and you call it like this

```
myOtherMethod: function() {
    // will be empty
    var stuff = this.getSomeStuff();
}
```

you can convert it to a promise:

```
getSomeStuff: function() {
    return new Promise (function(resolve, reject) {
        // some code
        oModel.read(sPath, {
            success: function() {
                myStuff = [1,2,3,4];
                // tell the caller that the promise is fullfilled
                // also pass the data to the caller
                resolve(myStuff);
            },
            error: function() {}
        });
    });
}
```

and call it like this

```
myOtherMethod: function() {
    this.getSomeStuff().then(function(stuff) {
        // stuff contains [1,2,3,4]
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just put your return inside the success call:

```
oDataModel.read("(some name)", {
        filters: oFilter,
        success: function (results, error) {
            //sap.m.MesageToast.show(results);
            var data = results.results;

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                aCustomSelectionVariant07.push({
                    path: "InspectionLot",
                    value1: data[i].InspectionLot,
                    operator: "EQ",
                    value2: null,
                    sign: "I"
                });
            }
            // var aCustomSelectionVariant07 =[];
            var oCustomSelectionVariant07 = {
                path: "InspLotRsltRecgStatus",
                operator: "BT",
                value1: "1",
                value2: "2",
                sign: "I"
            };
            aCustomSelectionVariant07.push(oCustomSelectionVariant07);

            oCustomSelectionVariant07 = {
                path: "InspectionLotType",
                operator: "BT",
                value1: "10",
                value2: "11",
                sign: "I"
            };
            aCustomSelectionVariant07.push(oCustomSelectionVariant07);

            return {
                selectionVariant: aCustomSelectionVariant07,
                ignoreEmptyString: true
            };
        },
        error: function (error) {
            sap.m.MesageToast.show(error);
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi Itachi, tried same not working as it is a custom.controller in OVP extension.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your Answers,
It got fixed by changing OdataModel Version,
earlier was using **(sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel)** so Async: false was not working,
by changing it to **(sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel)** it is working fine.
Please have a look at code.

```js
var oDataModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sUrl);

 oDataModel.read("/someName", {
    async: false,
    filters: oFilter,
    success: function (results, error) {
     var data = results.results;
          }
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. This solution, however, should **not** be encouraged as the mentioned `ODataModel` has become deprecated since many years and together with `async: false`, it sends many requests via [*sync XHR*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request) which is **also deprecated** by the web platform in general. Please do **not** use deprecated modules and APIs. Work with event handlers and promises as [suggested by Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57143123/5846045).